# Golang: Help registering a function into templates

Tags: templates, go

I'm trying to add to my templates a function to "humanize"(https://gowalker.org/github.com/dustin/go-humanize) the output, but seems something I'm doing wrong because I'm getting this error:

panic: template: dashboard.tmpl:192: function "humanizeTime" not defined

```
func renderTemplate(w http.ResponseWriter, name string, data map[string]interface{}) error {
    //functions for templates
    templateFuncs := template.FuncMap{
        "humanizeTime": func(t time.Time) string {
            return humanize.Time(t)
        },
    }
    tmpl := Templates[name+".tmpl"].Funcs(templateFuncs)
    w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "text/html; charset=utf-8")

    err := tmpl.ExecuteTemplate(w, name, data)
    if err != nil {
        log.Printf("Error rendering template: %s", err.Error())
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        return errors.New("Error trying to render template")
    }
    return nil
}
```

Added:
I am defining and loading on init() my templates Map:

```
var Templates      map[string]*template.Template

if Templates == nil {
    Templates = make(map[string]*template.Template)
}
layouts, err := filepath.Glob("templates/*.tmpl")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
for _, layout := range layouts {
    Templates[filepath.Base(layout)] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(layouts...))
}
```

I just change my definition to:

```
for _, layout := range layouts {
    Templates[filepath.Base(layout)] = template.Must(template.ParseFiles(layouts...)).Funcs(templateFuncs)
}
```

But doesn't work yet, I got the same error: not defined.

Please could somebody give me a hand with that? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, finally this solution works done for my case, based on Not_a_Golfer help:

```
for _, layout := range layouts {
    t := template.New("t").Funcs(templateFuncs)
    Templates[filepath.Base(layout)], err = t.ParseFiles(layouts...)
    if err != nil {
        panic(err)
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `Parse()` on the template after attaching the funcs to it. I don't know how your template map is being defined, but assuming it's a map of template texts, the call should look like this:

```
tmpl := template.New(templateName).Funcs(template.FuncMap{
        ....  
        }).Parse(Templates[name+".tmpl"])
```

If `Templates` contains parsed templates, you need to attach the function when you're parsing them.

Comment: But I'm loading on init() all my templates, I just added my Templates map definition, thanks.

Comment: @Goku so you should register the function when you parse it.